# Comparing a set of grouped values to itself

Tags: sql, group-by

Let's say I have this simplified table containing data about people's flights (ID of the passenger and ID of the company he flew with):

```
+-------------+-----------+
| PassengerID | CompanyID |
+-------------+-----------+
|          14 |         1 |
|          14 |         3 |
|          14 |         4 |
|          20 |         1 |
|          20 |         2 |
|          20 |         5 |
|          20 |         5 |
|          36 |         5 |
|          36 |         5 |
|          36 |         5 |
|          41 |         1 |
|          41 |         1 |
|          41 |         2 |
|          41 |         2 |
+-------------+-----------+
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get all Passengers who flew with more than 1 company and also who had same number of flights with each company they flew with.

I expect to get this result:

```
+-------------+
| PassengerID |
+-------------+
|          14 |
|          41 |
+-------------+
```

Explanation:
GOOD ID's:
14 - flew with 3 companies, 1 flight with each
41 - flew with 2 companies, 2 flights with each

BAD ID's:
20 - flew with 3 companies BUT 2 flights with one company and 1 flight per others
36 - flew with just 1 company

I tried to think about it like I would GROUP BY PassengerID and CompanyID while adding COUNT of CompanyID so I'll get something like this:

```
+-------------+-----------+------------------+
| PassengerID | CompanyID | COUNT(CompanyID) |
+-------------+-----------+------------------+
|          14 |         1 |                1 |
|          14 |         3 |                1 |
|          14 |         4 |                1 |
|          20 |         1 |                1 |
|          20 |         2 |                1 |
|          20 |         5 |                2 |
|          36 |         5 |                3 |
|          41 |         1 |                2 |
|          41 |         2 |                2 |
+-------------+-----------+------------------+
```

Then I had idea to use HAVING COUNT(PassengerID)>1 to get rid of ID 36 but for that I would have to group that again by just PassengerID.

Then I would use a self-join to compare COUNTs within same Passengers but I stuck on problem with PassengerID 20 because self-join will join these rows:

```
+-------------+-----------+------------------+
| PassengerID | CompanyID | COUNT(CompanyID) |
+-------------+-----------+------------------+
|          20 |         1 |                1 |
|          20 |         2 |                1 |
+-------------+-----------+------------------+
```

and will ignore the wrong row with the same PassengerID:

```
+-------------+-----------+------------------+
| PassengerID | CompanyID | COUNT(CompanyID) |
+-------------+-----------+------------------+
|          20 |         5 |                2 |
+-------------+-----------+------------------+
```

I haven't tried to execute this query, just thinking about the possible solution so it may not work this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would two levels of aggregation:

```
select PassengerID
from (select PassengerID, CompanyID, count(*) as numflights
      from flights f
      group by PassengerID, CompanyID
     ) f
group by PassengerID
having count(*) > 1 and                     -- more than one flight
       min(numflights) = max(numflights);   -- all the same number
```

Answer (score 1):

I select the PassengerIDs along with the company counts and then select the groups corresponding to the criteria in an outer select

```
select PassengerID
from (
select PassengerID, count(*) as c
from yourtable
group by PassengerID, CompanyID) t
group by PassengerID
having min(c) = max(c) and count(*) > 1
```